# TortoiseSVN - Repository on localhost, then working copies on localhost and online. Possible?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

I am attempting to use tortoiseSVN to solve a small problem which I am having.

I have a development laptop, and develop the majority of my websites on it.
If however I am on the move, and someone sends me an SMS reporting a bug for example, I often login to my ftp on any computer there an then, and fix the website 'live' per se.

If i then make an additional change on my development laptop, I often forget about the live change that I have made, and as a result lose it.

As such, I am looking to use tortoiseSVN to alleviate this problem.

My hosting account is a shared hosting account with hostgator which does NOT support SVN repositorys.

Am I correct to think that the way SVN works is that my 'live' copy MUST be the repository? Or am I missing the point?

Could someone explain how I would go about achieving what I want, even if it requires a hosting change.. or perhaps an alternative which suits my situation better..?

Many Thanks.

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you mean by "live" copy, but here is how you work with SVN.

First you have a svn server, this can be on your laptop, but should preferably be on separate with automated backups etc.

Then on your local machine you have the working copy. The working copy is a mostly a clone of the content on the server, but with your local modifications. When you are satisfied with your local modifications you commit (submit) the changes to the server. If you are not satisfied with your local changes you can easily revert to the version on the server (or an older version).

To get things to your production environment has nothing to do with svn. This is called a deployment process or release process. A deployment process typically compiles, backs an installer or collects files to be installed and finally installs/copies the result to your production environment.

The "master" copy of your application/web site should be on the svn server. To get something into production you run a script or follow a manual procedure to get the content from a working copy to the production.

By using an svn server as the master copy instead of your laptop you don't solve the problem of missing updates when you "cheat" by editing files directly in your production environment. But if you have remote shell access (ssh) you can have a local working copy on the production server, edit stuff in the working copy and check them in by command line svn tools.

**Edit**
To clarify: your "live" copy should ***absolutely*** not be the repository. The repository is not structured like a regular file tree with regular files in it. More like a sequence of changesets.
Your "live" copy should ***preferably*** not be a working copy either. The working copy contains special folders and files to keep track of "stuff" that you don't want on your public web site. Your live copy should be a copy of relevant files in a working copy. Either with `copy *.html /www-folder/` or [`svn export`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html) or some more elaborate method.

Comment: Well.. my current hosting account does not allow a SVN repository setup, so it'll have to be on my laptop.

Are you essentially saying that I should NOT be editing my LIVE version.. I.E The version people can see on the internet, but rather if I am in charge of the deployment of the site, I should make sure that my working copy is up to date, and then manually upload all the files etc..?

The concern here is that if there is a one line bug for example, I have to update my working file, update the repository, and then go to the effort of re uploading the one file.. Is that what you are suggest?

Comment: There are lots of external svn hosts you can pick from. If your hosting provider gives you shell access they don't need to support svn hosting, you can just run the svn client on your current host and keep a local working copy there. You can then ftp files to and from that working copy when you edit, then commit via the remote shell and execute your deployment script (like `copy ./*.html /www-dir/site/`).

Comment: I'm just saying that I won't by any services from a company I know write stuff right into production without prior testing and without any trace of what has been done.

Comment: Many Thanks.
Having followed: http://chrismweb.com/2011/02/24/svn-in-shared-hosting-with-hostgator/

I have set up a repository online. Now I will setup a working copy on both my computers that connects to this repository. This way if the repo has a newer version, on my pc there will be a red cross overlaying the image, and i can then update my version...

In terms of the live version.. once my repository is up to date/when i edit my working copy and commit it, i should then use shell access to deploy it/make it live..?

Have I understood your suggestion correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it sounds like your are on the right track except one detail. TortoiseSVN does show red crosses automatically when your repository has changed, only when your working copy has changed. To see if you have remote changes you can use [SVN Notifier](http://svnnotifier.tigris.org/) or [CommitMonitor](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor.html).

Comment: Thomas, regarding your first comment here - yes, that's how it HAS to be.  You should never modify the "production" site (your web site) directly. Edit on your laptop, copy it to the execution environment (preferably a test clone, but I realize that sometimes all you have is the "live" site, so sure, do that). If you like what you see, commit the change on your local. I wouldn't do it "manually", you can use an app like WinSCP to sync the folders (minus the .svn sub-folers), so it's pretty simple. Edit locally, sync, test, and if you like, commit. If you don't like, revert, sync, voila.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best answer is to use **a distributed versioning system** where your web-site is a **mirror branch or directly the repository** (or working copy, it's the same in DVCS).
So you benefit directly from your version control !

You can use Bazaar, Git or mercurial to do so, (or any other DVCS, it's just the major ones).

Comment: I've just gotten the hang of tortoisesvn :) Thanks to Albin's help..

TridenT, am I correct to think that Bazzar/Git/Mercurial make the live version (as ive described it) the repository.. and then I can have many working copies on many pcs?

Is there any tortoisesvn esque program for use with these?

Comment: yes, this is exact. And of course you have TortoiseBzr, TortoiseGit & TortoiseHg. Even if you just start with SVN, have a look to Bazaar and Mercurial (Hg), they are **very** similar to SVN.